# How to use INSERT INTO --- SELECT with new timestamp?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a small website, that keep tracks of students information,
When someone makes an update on one of the students I want to archive a copy of the previous record, I know that doing this makes a copy of the current data.

```
"INSERT INTO archives SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = $id"
```

But I want to include the date when the edit was made, so I tried this, but it produces the following error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

"INSERT INTO archives SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = $id, archive_date = $new_date"
```

---

Trying the following query - same error produced

```
INSERT INTO archives  (val, val1, val2, val3, new_date) SELECT (val, val1, val2, val3, now()) FROM students  WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: Remove the brackets around the value list in the SELECT clause

Comment: Which is it? [tag:sql-sever] or [tag:mysql]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should list all the columns and then you can set the value:

```
insert into archives ( . . ., archive_date) -- col list here
    select . . ., now()    -- or whatever function you are using for the current time
    from students
    where id = ?;
```

Remember to pass the `id` as a parameter.

EDIT:  (based on the edit to your question)

```
INSERT INTO archives  (val, val1, val2, val3, new_date) 
    SELECT val, val1, val2, val3, now()    -- or whatever function you are using for the current time
    FROM students
    WHERE id = $id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question implementing your response, but I keep getting the same error. I'm think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @pedro . . . You have an extra set of parentheses.

Comment: strongly recommend always using utc_timestamp() instead of now() to generate stored values

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the default value of the column to `NOW()`:

```
ALTER TABLE archives MODIFY COLUMN archive_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

When you execute your working `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO archives (col1, col2, .....) -- no need to list archive_date 
SELECT col1, col2, ..... 
FROM students 
WHERE id = $id
```

the column `archive_date` will get its default value and you don't have to supply any value for it.

Comment: Worth noting that to use a default value the INSERT must list the columns being inserted in to. Then, only columns not mentioned in the list will pick up their defaults.

Comment: @MatBailie correct, I will include it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the table `archives` already exists and the number of columns in the `archives` table does not match the number of columns in your `INSERT INTO` statement. That is the reason your error message mentions a column count `execute failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

To get past the issue, you have two choices: either add a column to the `archives` table, or `DROP` the `archives` table and recreate it with the missing column.

To add a new column to the `archives` table you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE archives 
ADD ArchiveDate DATETIME NULL;
```

Note that the new `ArchiveDate` column must have a default value of `NULL` because all the existing rows will not have a value. Now you can add data doing something like (from your question it looks like you are generating the SQL in the application layer so modify the code as appropriate):

```
INSERT INTO archives 
SELECT *, $new_date AS ArchiveDate
FROM students 
WHERE id = $id
```

If you want to start over with a new `archives` table, you can `DROP` it and recreate it:

```
DROP TABLE archives
```

Then you would do the same `INSERT INTO` as shown above.